# for jquery is there any error thrown when manipulating a dom element that doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I'm not checking if a DOM element exists before I manipulate it and jquery does not seem to throw any errors, even if it doesn't exist.

```
$('.test').addClass('hide');
```

where the test class doesn't exist, but this doesn't throw any errors.

So is this expected? should I be checking if it exists first?

Comment: This is expected behaviour. jQuery will not error when calling a method on a jQuery object which is empty.

Comment: This time it gets empty array and loops via it, so no error thrown. But if you try to get JS object, then it can throw error, e.g. `$('.tests')[0].value`

Comment: Okay got it, so no need to check if it exists first for jquery?

Comment: [Nope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989907/519413)

Comment: the link you shared is explain the speed difference between the two, saying that wrapping it in a if condition is better, i am asking in terms of errors if there is a difference. And the answer is no

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if ($('.test').length) {
   // do stuff
}
```

With JS only:

```
document.querySelector('non existing') // => null
```

Comment: You could do this, but in jQuery it's a waste of time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989907/519413

Comment: Agree. I just answered the question on how to test whether an element exists.

Comment: @Constantin in which case you would direct OP to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery :)